# Answering questions that belong on other sites

Tags: discussion, migration

What is the etiquette for answering questions that belong on other sites? For example I considered answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499798/security-problems-when-extending-a-web-application-in-sharepoint) but instead saw it should be on Server Fault so left a comment accordingly and marked to close. Someone has now answered that question correctly.

Considering the primary goal of the site (I think) is to answer questions, is it more important to answer and follow up the admin work of moving the question later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should still answer the question, while it's not yet moved.

In case edits are made to the question after it's moved you can always go to the other site and edit your answer accordingly. If the question doesn't change, you're answer is valid, regardless on which site you answered it.

Comment: I agree.  Go ahead and answer.  The point of migration is to get the question in front of the right audience, not to punish the OP for asking in the wrong place.  We still want to help them.